# Create nav bar with title on left and buttons on right

Tags: html, css, navbar

This is what my nav bar looks like right now:
[image]

This is what I want it to look like (with the title on the left and the buttons on the right):
[image]

I separated the nav bar into a left aligned list for the title and a right aligned list for the buttons, but for some reason, the two lists are stacking up on top each other instead being on one line. How do I create the nav bar above?

**HTML**

```
<div class = "navBarWrapper">
   <div class="top bar">
        <ul class = "left">
            <li class = "title">Photo Albums</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class = "right">
            <li class = "buttons"> <a class = "iconLink" href = ""><img class = "iconNotHover" src = "images/uploadImage.png" alt = "uploadImage" width = "40" align = "middle"/></a></li>
            <li class = "buttons"> <a href = "login.html" class="otherPages">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navBarWrapper {
  position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;

}

.left {
    text-align: left;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

.bar {
  height: 8.02%;
}


.bar li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Does that answer your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use `text-align` to move a block element to the left or right. That will only align inline elements within a block element to the left or right, and the block element will still be on it's own row.

You could float the left/right elements to the left/right, but I would use flexbox on the parent, `justify-content: space-between` to separate left/right, and `align-items` to align them vertically however you want.

```css
.navBarWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar {
  height: 8.02%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.bar li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBarWrapper">
  <div class="top bar">
    <ul class="left">
      <li class="title">Photo Albums</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="buttons">
        <a class="iconLink" href=""><img class="iconNotHover" src="images/uploadImage.png" alt="uploadImage" width="40" align="middle" /></a>
      </li>
      <li class="buttons"> <a href="login.html" class="otherPages">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to float them, here's that layout with `overflow: auto` on `.bar` to clear the floats.

```css
.navBarWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.bar {
  height: 8.02%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.bar li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBarWrapper">
  <div class="top bar">
    <ul class="left">
      <li class="title">Photo Albums</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="buttons">
        <a class="iconLink" href=""><img class="iconNotHover" src="images/uploadImage.png" alt="uploadImage" width="40" align="middle" /></a>
      </li>
      <li class="buttons"> <a href="login.html" class="otherPages">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the flex method, but when I first load the file. It looks like the image in my answer. Then when I uncheck and check the `justify-content: space-between;` in the inspector's panel, it looks like your code snippet.

Comment: @15ongm are you saying this happens on your personal website? does my demo work?

Comment: Yes, it happens on my personal website; your demo works. I also tried doing it using the floats method and I noticed that I had to check and uncheck `float: left` to get the nav bar with all the text and images aligned on 1 line.  Force refresh didn't solve my problem either.

Comment: @15ongm it's your responsibility to give us enough context to solve your problem. Per your post, I believe I've answered your question sufficiently with 2 solutions. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @15ongm to attempt to guess at why it isn't working on your personal site means I would just be guessing and that isn't what SO is about and it's a waste of yours and my time. Here's a link about creating a [mcve].

Comment: okay isee thanks! I solved my own issue using this link: https://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/2c2xmp/when_a_bug_in_your_site_might_actually_a_bug_in/#bottom-comments. Essentially, I removed float left and right using jquery and then reapplied float left & right after 1 millisecond.

Comment: @15ongm awesome :)